# Sorting through a multidimensional array in python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, variable-assignment

I am trying to find the most efficient method of sorting, testing and assignment  through a multi-array in python.

**Here is a multi array**: containing data of users

```
persons = [['Person 1', 15, 'USA', 'BLACK'],
           ['Person 2', 12, 'AUS', 'WHITE'],
           ['Person 3', 34, 'CAN', 'PINK'],
           ['Person 4', 18, 'CHINA', 'BLUE']]
```

Here is my code for sorting through. It doesn't work. Result: Getting 'NOT FOUND!'.

```
    persons_profile = []
    for i, item in enumerate(persons):

        persons_profile .append(item)
        if(persons_profile [0] == 'Person 1'):
             person_id = persons_profile [0]
             person_age = persons_profile [1]
             person_country = persons_profile [2]
             person_color = persons_profile [3]
             print "Person id", persons_profile [O]
             some_function()

        elif(persons_profile [0] == 'Person 2'):
             person_id = persons_profile [0]
             person_age = persons_profile [1]
             person_country = persons_profile [2]
             person_color = persons_profile [3]
             print "Person id", persons_profile [O]
             some_function()

        elif(persons_profile [0] == 'Person 3'):
            person_id = persons_profile [0]
             person_age = persons_profile [1]
             person_country = persons_profile [2]
             person_color = persons_profile [3]
             print "Person id", persons_profile [O]
             some_function()

        elif(persons_profile [0] == 'Person 4'):
            person_id = persons_profile [0]
             person_age = persons_profile [1]
             person_country = persons_profile [2]
             person_color = persons_profile [3]
             print "Person id", persons_profile [O]
             some_function()

        else:
            print "NOT FOUND!"
```

What is the best way to sort and test if the item 0, 1, 2, 3 in index 0, 1, 2, 3  in the multi-array equal something?

Answer (score 1):

```
persons_profile.append(item)
```

Here you are putting `list` item into `list` persons_profile.

and here:

```
if persons_profile[0] == 'Person 1':
```

You are comparing `str` with `list`.

And finally since it always `False` you are going to `else` branch.

Comment: Hi @xi_ How do I go about comparing an item of str/int type inside a list inside list persons_profile? – Code2016 12 mins ago

Comment: @Code2016 you should go inside list: `if persons_profile[0][0] == 'Person 1':`